# py2neo can't create relationship for indexed nodes?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm using py2neo 1.5.1 and neo4j 1.9.1. The following code throws a lot of errors due to the create relationship line, based on my testing. Can anybody explain why?

```
from py2neo import neo4j,node,rel

graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
entity = graph_db.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "Entity", config={"type":"fulltext", "provider":"lucene"})

batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)
n1 = batch.get_or_create_indexed_node(entity, "name_type","e1_t1",{"name":"e1","type":"t1"})
n2 = batch.get_or_create_indexed_node(entity, "name_type","e2_t2",{"name":"e2","type":"t2"})
batch.create(rel(n1, "TEST", n2))
results = batch.submit()
```

Comment: I experimented more, and found that if I use batch.get_or_create_indexed_relationship instead. The issue is gone.

Comment: What is the rationaled for requiring for relationship between indexed nodes to be indexed as well?

Comment: It is only required if you want to create unique relationships, I think.